# iBook PPC: Change Airport's MAC Address

Tags: mac-address, airport-extreme, osx-tiger

I have been attempting to set-up [HomePass](https://gbatemp.net/threads/how-to-have-a-homemade-streetpass-relay.352645/) for my 3DS on my iBook. I basically need to [change my Airport's MAC Address and share my internet](https://gbatemp.net/threads/how-to-have-a-homemade-streetpass-relay.352645/#post-4736991) in order to make this work, but I am having trouble changing the MAC Address. Below is a rendition of my iBook's Terminal (it runs web browsers too slow to copy and paste):

```
me$ ifconfig en1 | grep ether
    ether MY:DE:FA:UL:TM:AC
me$ sudo ifconfig en1 ether MY:DE:SI:RE:DM:AC
Password:
me$ ifconfig en1 | grep ether
    ether MY:DE:FA:UL:TM:AC
me$ ifconfig
lo0: flags=...
    inet ...
    inet6 ...
    inet6 ...
gif0: flags= ...
stf0: flags= ...
en0: flags= ...
    inet6 ....
    inet6 ....
    inet ...
    ether MY:DE:SI:RE:DM:AC
    media ...
    supported media ...
en1: flags ...
    inet6 ...
    inet ...
    ether MY:DE:FA:UL:TM:AC
    media ...
    supported media ...
fw0: flags= ...
    lladdr ...
    media ...
    supported media ...
```

I have done a number of google searches (like "os x 10.4 change airport mac address," "os x tiger, change en1," and "spoof mac address os x tiger") and I am coming up short. My questions: Is it possible to change my Airport's MAC Address, the `en1`? And, if so, how?

Computer & Airport info: `iBook G4, PPC, Mac OS X 10.4.11 | 1.33 GHz, 768 MB DDR | AirPort Extreme, Version 405.1 | BSD Device name: en1 | IPv4: DHCP, IPv6 Auto` Also, I can add to any of the information, just let me know what is needed.